# The difference between "erste" and "zunächst"

Tags: meaning, usage

I understand that both "erste" and "zunächst" mean first. Is there any difference in meaning or usage between them?

Comment: Have a look into your dictionary - This might help. Especially look at what type of word (adjective, adverb)  each of them is.

Comment: There is a subtle difference that a dictionary might not explain. Zunächst is  a takeoff on "next" and means "first" going forward. Erst means "first" in a series that can start at any time. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the **grammatical usage** of both words is different: This means the position in the sentence etc. is different.

The **meaning** differs the following way:

The word "*erste*" indicates that something is or happens first in an order of multiple things.

Example:

> Today they played 20 songs in the radio. "I like Stackexchange" was the **first** song they played.
>
> Das Lied "I like Stackexchange" war das **erste** Lied, das gespielt wurde.

The word "*zunächst*" is used to indicate that something happens but something different happens before.

Example:

> We will play the song "I love German language" in a few Minutes but **first** we will play "I like Stackexchange".
>
> ... aber **zunächst** werden wir "I like Stackexchange" spielen.

In many cases both words can be used.